# How can we prove $(a - b)/(c - d) = (b - a)/(d - c)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, real-numbers

I happened upon a problem where the proposed solution involved switching the order of two subtractions, one in the numerator of a fraction, and one in the denominator of that fraction. That is, it was assumed that $\dfrac{a - b}{c - d} = \dfrac{b - a}{d - c}$, with I suppose the implicit assumption that $c \neq d$.

I don't recall ever seeing a proof of that statement, and when I attempted to search for someone else's proof of it, I couldn't find anything. Although maybe there's a name for this property of subtraction and division that would have produced some better results. I was also unable to quickly prove this on my own.

So I'm wondering how, given $ a, b, c, d \in \Bbb{R}, c \neq d$, how $\dfrac{a - b}{c - d} = \dfrac{b - a}{d - c}$ can be proved. I would also be interested in whether there is a name for this property, and/or a name for the procedure of swapping the order of subtractions like this.

Comment: $(a-b)=-(b-a)$.

Comment: You could also just cross-multiply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we have
$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{k\alpha}{k\beta}$$

where $k \ne 0$ and $\beta \ne 0$, since we just multiply the numerator and the denominator by the same constant.

Here $k=-1, \alpha = a-b, \beta = c-d$.